# IdentityContext with DataContext

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I have a problem with contexts. The application will manage warehouses. Each user can have different access to the slides.

The access itself with its id will be described in the `Permission` class.

This is all stored in the `DataContext`.

```cs
public DbSet<UserPermission> UserPermission { get; set; }
public DbSet<Permission> Permission { get; set; }

public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set;}
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
    public DateTime Created { get; set;}
    public DateTime Updated { get; set;}
    public string PermissionName { get; set;}
    public string PermissionDescription { get; set;}
}
```

User permissions will be stored here.

```cs
public class UserPermission
{
    public string UserPermissionId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set;}
    public int PermissionID { get; set;}
    public int DepartmentID { get; set;}
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
    public DateTime Created { get; set;}
    public DateTime Updated { get; set;}
    public Permission Permission { get; set;}
    public ApplicationUser User {get; set; }
}
```

By injecting an identity into the project, an `identityContext` is added. I customized the user class like this.

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermission { get; set; } = new List<UserPermission>();
}
```

When performing migrations, I have duplicate tables in the database.

1. Do I need to have two contexts or can I do everything in one, if so, in which `DataContext` or `identityContext`?
2. How to make the `UserPermission` field immediately populated during user authentication, so that you can execute?

   ```cs
   var p = context.user.UserPermission.tolist()
   ```